# Insert detail line items at the same time as master line item is created

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, telerik-grid

Technology: ASP.Net, Telerik, C#4, linq2sql

I have a master-detail grid that displays, updates and inserts OK. I would like to add the capability to add detail records to a new master record, then save both. Essentially, it makes the user experience nicer - now, they have to add a master record, save it, then expand the (empty) detail grid and insert a record.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on what you're asking but what I think you want to do is this:

Insert the new Master Record. 
Select the ID of the new record (or whatever is the PK)
Insert the new Detail Record with the FK to the new Master

You can do all of these things programatically in sequence so the user won't have to do it manually.  Not sure if it can be done directly from a databound grid, but someone else may have insight on that.

Hope that is of some help...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me try an example - the master-detail could be order-orderitems. The problem is that the user gets an order, so the user wants to create the order and enter the items all at the same time. I could do this with a custom form, but I was hoping that the master/detail grid handled the work for me, since I already have edit templates in place for both order and order item...